# Getting customers who took all loans

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a homework question. I want to find the customers who took all loans. The table is as follows.

```
Schema:
loan (number (PKEY), type, min_rating)
borrower (cust (PKEY), no (PKEY))

Sample tables:
number | type     | min_rating
------------------------------
L1     | student  | 500
L2     | car      | 550
L3     | house    | 500
L4     | car      | 700
L5     | car      | 900

cust  | no 
-----------
Jim   | L2
Tom   | L1
Tom   | L2
Tom   | L3
Tom   | L4
Tom   | L5
Bob   | L3
```

The answer here will be Tom.

Now, for learning purposes, the requirement is I'm **not** allowed to count the total number of loans and comparing the borrower's number of loans to that, which totally works if I could use it.

So what I was thinking of was to see that all the borrower's loans exists in the loan table. I tried doing double negation by first getting the customers which do not have all loans, but this doesn't work. Any hints on how do I go about doing this? And is this the best way to do it considering what I'm not allowed to do?

I don't think it's as complicated as it seems, fyi, but I can't figure it out myself.

Comment: The problem is if you check for all the loans be on loan_type... doesnt say if you have all loans.

Comment: Any particular rdbms? Sql Server Mysql?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sorry if the description was confusing as I shortened the table to make it easier to understand but apparently it was sort of needed. In this example all the loans are different despite having the same type, because they all have a certain minimum credit rating required. And I'm running this on mySQL.

Comment: You want the customers who didn't not take any loans

Comment: @Strawberry he want the customers taking all loans and live from cookies and jello.

Comment: @maregor You were on the right track with double negation

Comment: You can solve this by finding out which customers are on foodstamps, due to them having to pay back more loans than they can afford.  Have a table of foodstamps collected by a customer, and the customer collecting the most will be the one with the most loans to pay back at an extortionate APR

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376378)**</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE #loan(
   number VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL 
  ,type   VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #loan(number,type) VALUES ('L1','student');
INSERT INTO #loan(number,type) VALUES ('L2','car');
INSERT INTO #loan(number,type) VALUES ('L3','house');
INSERT INTO #loan(number,type) VALUES ('L4','car');
INSERT INTO #loan(number,type) VALUES ('L5','car');


CREATE TABLE #borrower(
   cust  VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL 
  ,no VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #borrower VALUES ('Jim','L2'), ('Tom','L1'), ('Tom','L2'), ('Tom','L3'),
                             ('Tom','L4'), ('Tom','L5'), ('Bob','L3');

SELECT cust
FROM (
  SELECT b.cust, COUNT(DISTINCT type) AS c
  FROM #loan l
  JOIN #borrower b
    ON l.number = b.no
    GROUP BY b.cust) AS s
WHERE s.c = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT type) FROM #loan);
```

## EDIT:

<kbd>**[LiveDemo2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376402)**</kbd>

No need for count:

```
SELECT main.cust
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT cust FROM #borrower) AS main
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT sub2.cust
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT cust, type
    FROM #borrower b
    JOIN #loan l
      ON b.no = l.number) as sub
    RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT b.cust, s.type
    FROM #borrower b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM #loan) AS s) AS sub2
      ON sub.cust = sub2.cust AND sub.type = sub2.type
    WHERE sub.cust IS NULL
) AS sub3
  ON main.cust = sub3.cust
WHERE sub3.cust IS NULL;
```

How it works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub2.cust
  FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT cust, type
FROM #borrower b
JOIN #loan l
  ON b.no = l.number) as sub
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT b.cust, s.type
    FROM #borrower b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM #loan) AS s) AS sub2
  ON sub.cust = sub2.cust AND sub.type = sub2.type
WHERE sub.cust IS NULL;
```

It will returns customers who hasn't all loans.
Then you just remove them from all customers.

## EDIT2:

Using `EXCEPT` (SQL Server):

<kbd>**[LiveDemo3](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376405)**</kbd>

```
SELECT main.cust
FROM #borrower AS main
EXCEPT 
(
  SELECT cust
  FROM (
   SELECT b.cust, s.type
   FROM #borrower b
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM #loan) AS s
   EXCEPT
   SELECT cust, type
   FROM #borrower b
   JOIN #loan l
     ON b.no = l.number ) AS sub
)
```

Comment: Sorry lad, but for some reason OP cant count the total of load_type

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Check now

Comment: Still the same. OP say you cant count distinct type and cant count total student

Comment: He say is a homework, and is not allowed.  I still trying to find a workaround.

Comment: @lad2025 Sorry, I think it's in order to exercise using IN/NOT IN/EXISTS or something like that instead of COUNT, etc.

Comment: Looks like we were on the same track at the same time, lad. :)

Comment: @xathien It will be much more readable if MySQL supports **EXCEPT/MINUS** operator.

Comment: @maregor See how it is easy when you can use EXCEPT :) If you can use ORACLE just change EXCEPT with `MINUS`

Comment: well done, But now i wonder what will teacher think? because looks way over the top for a student

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza He can say `When I wrote this, only God and I understood what I was doing Now, God only knows` :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a distinct number of types of loans, simply join once to check for each type:

```
SELECT bStudent.cust
FROM borrower bStudent
JOIN loan hasStudent ON bStudent.no = hasStudent.no AND hasStudent.type = 'student'
JOIN borrower bCar ON bStudent.cust = bCar.cust
JOIN loan hasCar ON bCar.no = hasCar.no AND hasCar.type = 'car'
JOIN borrower bHouse ON bStudent.cust = bHouse.cust
JOIN loan hasHouse ON bCar.no = hasHouse.no AND hasHouse.type = 'house';
```

The first join will get all borrowers with a student loan, the second set two joins will match borrowers that have a car loan, and the third set of two joins will match borrowers that have a house loan.

**UPDATE**

Okay, let's assume we don't know how many types of loans there are... Back to your double-negation idea! First step, map each borrower to their loan types:

```
SELECT cust, type
FROM borrower b
JOIN loan l
USING (no);
```

... then we'll find all of the different types of loans...

```
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM loan
```

... find persons who are missing some type of loan...

```
SELECT DISTINCT cust
FROM (SELECT cust, type
    FROM borrower b
    JOIN loan l
    USING (no)) custLoanTypes
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM loan) loanTypes
USING (type)
WHERE loanTypes.type IS NULL;
```

... and then subtract those from the distinct list of borrowers.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cust FROM borrower b
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT cust
    FROM (SELECT cust, type
        FROM borrower b
        JOIN loan l
        USING (no)) custLoanTypes
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM loan) loanTypes
    USING (type)
    WHERE loanTypes.type IS NULL) custsMissingALoan
USING (cust)
WHERE custsMissingALoan.cust IS NULL;
```

What a fun puzzle.

Comment: I was thinking in one similiar to this, but you need `left join` instead of `join`

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` would fetch me customers that don't have all three loans, whereas `[INNER] JOIN` gets me only the ones that do.

Comment: In your solution when new type of loan will be available, the query needs to be updated

Comment: @lad2025 yes, but this is a homework not a production. And you are right. xathien `JOIN` is the way to go.

Comment: There is no table specified, I just made my own for example purposes. Is there a way to query this without hardcoding?

Comment: See the update, with 295% more query building steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the following schema...

```
CREATE TABLE loan(
   loan_id CHAR(2) NOT NULL 
  ,type   VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO loan VALUES 
('L1','student'),
('L2','car'),
('L3','house'),
('L4','car'),
('L5','car');


CREATE TABLE borrower(
   name  VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL 
  ,loan_id CHAR(2) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO borrower VALUES 
('Jim','L2'),
('Tom','L1'), 
('Tom','L2'), 
('Tom','L3'), 
('Tom','L4'), 
('Tom','L5'), 
('Bob','L3');
```

... then it seems that you want to return the names of all users who do NOT appear in this list...

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.name 
           FROM borrower b 
           JOIN loan l 
           LEFT 
           JOIN borrower bx 
             ON bx.name = b.name 
            AND bx.loan_id = l.loan_id 
          WHERE bx.name IS NULL;

+------+
| name |
+------+
| Jim  |
| Bob  |
+------+
```